Everyone loves multiple endings!
Preface
While my other connect wall trundles along, I thought I'd write a second one to get the juices flowing.
A lot of games these days offer the player multiple endings. I thought I'd follow suit; this puzzle's full of them!
Wall











THAUMA
BUREAU
DEMO
THEFT


EGO
FIRE
DRAMA
IDIOM


CHROME
METAL
PLUTO
NEW


AUTO
PHLEGM
MEGA
LIT



Clues
Clue 1

 A few of the words have been slightly altered, to keep you on your toes.


Group 1:

 THAUMA, DRAMA, METAL, and LIT
 can all be followed by -(t)URGY

Group 2:

 BUREAU, DEMO, PLUTO, and AUTO
 can all be followed by -CRACY

Group 3:

 THEFT (actually KLEPTO), EGO, FIRE (actually PYRO), and MEGA (actually MEGALO)
 can all be followed by -MANIAC

Group 4:

 IDIOM, CHROME (actually CHROM), NEW (actually PNEU), and PHLEGM
 can all be followed by -(m)ATIC

Nice puzzle!

I think it's very much in keeping with the theme of this puzzle that you've found all the categories and an alternative way of solving them, hah hah. I wondered if anyone would do that. Not sure if I should give you the accept; you've got two words swapped, for what it's worth.

Is it rot13(NHGB naq ARJ (npghnyyl ARH)) that are swapped?

rot13(Lrf. Npghnyyl Carh, abg Arh. Irel jryy qbar!)

Very nice solve. Thanks for playing :)
